# If I install wicd will my computer automatically uninstall Network Manager?

Tags: networking, connection

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on a Compaq evoD500.

My computer randomly loses connection while the other computers in the house are still connected, so I know the problem is specific to my box. The other boxes are running windows XP.

I think Network Manager might be the problem and would like to try wicd, but I'm concerned that I might not be able to revert back to Network Manager if I need to.

Let me know if more info is needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wicd packages do not conflict with Network Manager. You can have both of them installed at the same time; this was [requested](http://bugs.debian.org/548978) by someone who wanted to use one for his VPN and the other for his Wifi. Just don't use them on the same interface, as they would step on each other's toes.

The packages did conflict in jaunty and karmic (I think, I may have gotten the versions wrong). Even then, you could have switched without losing your configuration. There are two ways to uninstall a package: you can *remove* it or *purge* it. Removing uninstalls the package but leaves the configuration files in place; purging also removes the configuration files in `/etc` even if you've modified them. When a package is automatically uninstalled due to a conflict, it is removed, not purged.

Comment: Could or should I copy network manager to a usb stick in case I completely lose connectivity?

Comment: @Rattlehead2000 Since you don't need to uninstall the package, you don't need to back up anything. If you did uninstall, the easiest way to retain the binary would be to run `aptitude download network-manager` which would leave the `.deb` file in `/var/cache/apt/archives` where `aptitude install network-manager` would pick it up (as long as you haven't flushed the cache in between).

Answer (score 0):

What I would like to recoment you is to try stop network-manager and connect to you network through terminal. If everything ok than you should try wicd else - search for drivers.

Depending to your OS version it doesn't remove network-manager or can ask you what to do.